# How to fetch the document mode of Internet Explorer in C# by page request

Tags: c#, asp.net, internet-explorer, browser, browser-detection

I have tried to fetch the document mode of internet explorer while page request in C#. but i failed on this. Please have a look on my tried codes snippets.

```
<code>
[C#]
BrowserCapabilities bcBrowser = new BrowserCapabilities( this.Page.Request );

</code>
```

but i unable to get the document mode of IE browsers in bcBrowser object. Please suggest me some ideas to fetch the document mode of IE 11 browser in C#

Thanks in advance.

Regards,
Gurunathan

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9430449/can-i-detect-ie-document-mode-on-the-server-side-using-the-httpbrowsercapabiliti

Comment: Thanks for suggestion @sandman but i really need the document mode which i set in developer tool manually. but it works fine with compatible mode. Please give some other suggestion